# making it so i'm always prompted for which program to use when opening files with certain extensions

Tags: windows-8.1, file-extension

I opened up a *.php file with Notepad in Windows 8.1 and now it's wanting to open every *.php file with Notepad. I can change the program it opens *.php files up with but I don't want it to always open them up with the same program. I *want* it to prompt me, asking me which program I want to use, every time I double click on a *.php file. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the following as a .REG file and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.php]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.php]
```

Answer (score 2):

That is called a *file association*.  If none exists for a given file-type, Windows will prompt you for a suitable program when you attempt to "open" a file having that type.

While the method for adding or modifying a *file association* has changed slightly over the past few releases of Windows, none provide a nice interface for *deleting* one.

According to *[How Do You Remove a Default File Association in Windows 7?](http://www.howtogeek.com/171932/how-do-you-remove-a-default-file-association-in-windows-7/?PageSpeed=noscript)*, that can be done by removing the registry key for the given suffix under this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

which normally is abbreviated:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

Comment: There is a program called unassoc.exe from http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/unassociate-file-types-windows-7-vista/ that will remove the associated program that was assigned. Oh wait, that's for Win 7 and Vista, although it should work in Win 8.